Get external ip of local server in php, FAST
I need to get ahold of my servers external IP number.
This is proving harder than I thought, so I need your help.
I do know that I can get the IP number of someone visiting the website a few different ways, like this:
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
That is not the case for the server however, since that will reply with "127.0.0.1", which isn't helpful as that isn't the external IP address.
The key to this is speed. I know several ways of getting the IP number, but not how to get it FAST.
I'm looking for fairly consistent speeds lower than 35 milliseconds on average, the lower the better of course
I am very well aware that I can use the exact same script on a different server, curl it and then get the servers IP number - that's what I am doing now, however that tends to be fairly slow, even after optimizing my curl script
file_get_contents is even slower.
checkip.dyndns.com or another server doesn't really impact much.
Not to mention inconsistent, in 5 curls it averages around 0.07 seconds.
   $ip_json = trim( file_get_contents('https://ipinfo.io/json') ); $ip_arr = json_decode($ip_json,true); echo $ip_arr['ip'];
is much slower, taking about 2 to 4 times as long as curling.
gethostbyname() won't work because it's not tied to a domain name
json_encode(net_get_interfaces(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
won't work bcause it's beehind a router
I've explored using exec($command);, to see if I can get it from the command prompt using ipconfig and whatever else I could think of, but it doesn't seem to be there either.
I did notice that rather than curl, I could speed things up by:

using XMLHttpRequest in javascript to return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] from the other server when I click a button that loads a new page for example
take the ip number and do yet another XMLHttpRequest as post to a local php file
save the ip number as a session $_SESSION['ip'] = $_POST['ip']; and then use the session variable
Resume the actual javascript functionality of the button in a callback
use the ip number in the exec($command); in php to get the actual external IP number.

It's a convoluted process, but it gets the IP number about three times as fast as curl.
However, it's still much slower than if I could find it locally somewhere.
And it's slower still than loading an iframe from the other server which tells me 2 things - 1. it can be fetched much faster and 2. The data I need is right there, but I don't know how to get at it from an external source in chrome.
I've toyed around with the idea of using other programming languages and create something with the exec command, redirecting the the request of the other server to place the header in the redirected url, curling the nameservers, etc but that's just theoretical at this point.
Is it possible to find the external IP of a server in a fast way? Ideally locally, but if not, then in some faster way?
Is it possible to replicate how the browser fetchees content for an iframe?

"I need to get ahold of my servers external IP number." - server addresses are generally fixed, so you look it up once in the server configuration and put it in a configuration file.  The real question here is 'Why do you need this?'

I was going to ask the same thing - what's the purpose of repeatedly looking it up, and what's the purpose of knowing it at all?

You've got a web server that doesn't have a domain and that's behind a router. Such a server doesn't know the external IP address of the internet connection. I think you're aware of that. However, I agree with TP that the IP probably won't change all that often, so instead of storing it in a session, which you have to do for each visitor, you could store it in a file, or database, for quick retrieval. You can then check it regularly, and update it when needed, using a process that's not so time-critical.

It's a bit weird, I'll grant you that - it's for detecting what the VPN is connected to. It accesses some content that is region specific, and also checks if the corporate VPN is switched on or not on the server. If it isn't in the right region/on the corporate VPN, then it can't access/update some things in the cron jobs.

Have you try https://ip2location.io/ip? It is using edges which is faster.

Thanks, I just tried it out: tffan.com/v1.JPG tffan.com/v2.JPG - ip2location takes twice as long as just using plain php to get the IP address in my case.
Although relevant, I think the main bottleneck for me is in how I query and get the data. into php.
